# Including header files in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

As you know the `getch()` and `getche()` functions don't work with the cygwin, a linux oriented one.

But can I include the conio.h header file of borland c and call the functions getch in my makefiles?

Will it work and can anyone tell me how to include the header files from different directories in cywgin.
I have a header file `strcal.h` in directory `c:/makk/string/`.

How do I include that header file in my makefile?

```
gcc -I/string small.c
```

It is not working and my current directory is makk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stdio.h`, there is a `getchar()` function which is what you need. You can't just bring across the Borland header file since that just declares the function, it doesn't define it. Standard C has no need for `getch()`.

To include header files in different areas, you use the `-I` directives of `gcc` to set up search paths.

So, if you have a `/xyz/myheader.h` file, you can do something like:

```
gcc -I /xyz myprogram.c
```

To get at `c:/makk/string/strcal.h`, you may have to use `gcc -I /cygdrive/c/makk/string` or, if you know you're actually *in* that `makk` directory, you can use `-I string` (note the lack of leading `/` since you want a relative path, not an absolute one).

Comment: but getchar() function it prints the character on the screen and it takes the input till u press the enter.but i want the character not to be displayed out.and take the input only once

Comment: @karthik, ISO C does not provide that functionality. If you want to do that in a UNIXy environment, you would set the terminal to raw mode so that you wouldn't have to wait for the newline - see tcgetattr and tcsetattr for details.

Comment: thank you paxdiablo i would check out the tcgetattr and tc setattr and thanks for lettin me know 'bout the including the header files